Part of the balance inside my wallet is locked
Part of the balance inside my wallet is locked
I noticed that this low inventory was repeated several times and my property lock dates were automatically extended
How do I unlock my balance?
thank you

Did you participate in the ASMB airdrop/"staking"? If yes, the IOTA tokens you received for it will be gradually released until August 2025. So in this case it is normal you have locked tokens in your wallet you can claim during the next months. You can of course do whatever you want with the balance you already received.
